# Variables in javascript switch cases?

Tags: javascript

I want to use variables as the values for each case in a switch statement, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
switch(key) {  

    case keyNext: 
      //go to next
      break;

    case keyPrev: 
      //go to prev
      break;
}
```

I really need the switch statement because unlike in this example, I have lots of different cases.

Why doesnt this work? Any workarounds for it?

**EDIT**: as said in the answers, this is perfectly valid. I was using properties of an object as the values for each case, and there was a syntax problem with it.

Comment: What is `key`? Is it `event.keycode`? Your `switch` is syntactically correct, but how are you mapping keycodes to `keyNext, keyPrev`? Are they defined by a framework?

Comment: Your code seems ok... Maybe add a snippet of some of your cases so I can help better? Since you have a lot of cases, maybe you have a syntax error somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to check against, see the following example. You just need to make sure they are declared and given a value. May need to see more of what your working with to see if the issue is arising elsewhere.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/KFCAg/3/)**

```
var keyNext = 1, // or "1" what have you,
    keyPrev = 2,
    key = keyPrev; // or key = 1

switch(key) {  

    case keyNext: 
      alert('Next');
      break;

    case keyPrev: 
      alert('Prev');
      break;
}
```

Comment: I see. Then my problem is somewhere else. My variables are actually properties of an object (I tried to simplify the question since I thought it was the same). Like appname.config.keyNext instead of keyNext. That should work too, right?